# Delphi .exe COM server starting oddity

Tags: delphi, com

I have a Win32 .exe written in Delphi Seattle that implements a COM interface to a function.
I'm confused by the way the server behaves if I call CreateOleObject() from inside the program itself.
The instancing model is set to `ciSingleInstance` so I would expect a new instance to be created at each call (assuming the previous instances are still running).

What actually happens is the first call does not create a new instance but the second does.
If the first call runs to completion the second instance again creates a new instance even though the program should be back to its default state.

How do I

a) force creation of a second instance on the first call, or
b) return the program to a really default state so that multiple runs to completion do not start a second instance.

Comment: The default state is "accept exactly one `CoCreateInstance` call, for the lifetime of this process". In light of this, your program appears to be working as expected. You probably run it by means other than `CoCreateInstance`, so it still waits for its one and only `CoCreateInstance` - but once it gets it, it won't take any more, ever.

Comment: "once per process lifetime" explains things and means if I call CreateOleObject() once, if the program is not being automated, gives an answer to my first question. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ciSingleInstance` is passed as [REGCLS_SINGLEUSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679697.aspx) to the internal call to [CoRegisterClassObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693407.aspx) which may be causing this unwanted behaviour.